# Omit port with Mule ESB http:request endpoint

Tags: http, mule

I'm trying to use the Mule ESB `http:request` endpoint to get data from *api.crossref.org*. I've found that I get a 404 if the port number is included. That is, this request succeeds:

```
GET http://api.crossref.org/works?filter=doi%3A10.1080%2F10573560601158461&sort=score&order=desc HTTP/1.1
Host: api.crossref.org
<blank line>
<blank line>
```

but this one fails:

```
GET http://api.crossref.org:80/works?filter=doi%3A10.1080%2F10573560601158461&sort=score&order=desc HTTP/1.1
Host: api.crossref.org:80
<blank line>
<blank line>
```

Is there a way to get to force Mule to omit the port number from the headers? This also happens with HTTPS and 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the Host header manually, meaning in a request builder:

Mule 3

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="test" method="GET">
    <http:request-builder>
        <http:header headerName="Host" value="api.crossref.org" />
    </http:request-builder>
</http:request>
```

Mule 4

```
  <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="test" method="GET">
    <http:headers>
      #[{"Host" : "api.crossref.org"}]
    </http:headers>
  </http:request>
```

Servers should handle the Host header with the port but unfortunately some do not. See the [HTTP Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-troubleshooting#host-header-misuse) for more details.
HTH

Comment: I am getting this exception : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 51; columnNumber: 25; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'http:request-builder'.

Comment: Which version of Mule are you using?

Comment: version of mule 4.0

Comment: Then see https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-troubleshooting#host-header-misuse for the correct syntax. The example I shared is for Mule 3.

Comment: Thanks, It is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just try port 80 for http and port 443 for https with your URL, which are default ports and it should work.